# erlang init error using tsung-recorder

Tags: erlang, tsung

I have setup Tsung to do some load testing on an ubuntu VM.  Tsung itself works fine if I write the setup scripts by hand, but I would like to use tsung-recorder to build my scripts dynamically through the browser.

When I start tsung-recorder I get the following error, however:

```
cpjolicoeur@vbox-ubuntu-koala:~$ tsung-recorder start
Starting Tsung recorder on port 8090
cpjolicoeur@vbox-ubuntu-koala:~$ {"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot load',error_handler,get_files}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

I'm no erlang expert (I have no erlang experience at all at the moment), so does anyone have any idea what is crashing and how I can fix it to get tsung-recorder working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says it cannot find the `error_handler` module. Either your Erlang install is corrupted, or for example the Erlang boot script is outdated, or is for another Erlang version.